# Invoking reports from REST API

Tags: cumulocity

The built-in Cockpit application provides an interface for creating Reports for exporting data such as measurements and alarms.

Is there a way to hook up a scheduled task such as an AWS Lambda cron/scheduled task to execute the report?

Can the report be delivered to anything other than an email address? 
AWS S3, Dropbox or similar would be great as they could then feed into an analytics workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST API to trigger the export generation is as follows:

/export/exports?configurationId={configurationId}

The configurationId is the ID of the managedObject that contains the report  configuration.

Currently the report will automatically send to the email address of the user that executed the request.
Maybe consider services like IFTTT or Zapier to forward the attachment to e.g. Dropbox

Comment: Thanks.

Is this documented in the REST reference guide? 

I didn't find it, but maybe I missed it.